# Why didn't Amy and Rory get a dark alter ego?

Tags: doctor-who, amy-pond

In the Doctor Who episode *[Amy's Choice](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amy%27s_Choice_%28Doctor_Who%29)*, how come the Doctor got a dark alter ego (i.e. The Dream Lord) but Amy and Rory didn't get one? Wouldn't it be logical for them to have one too?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

### Because they're too 'good'.

This is addressed explicitly by the Doctor at the end of the episode:

> RORY: So that was the Dream Lord then? Those little specks.
>   DOCTOR: No, no. No. Sorry, wasn't it obvious? The Dream Lord was me. Psychic pollen. It's a mind parasite. It feeds on everything dark in you, gives it a voice, turns it against you. I'm nine hundred and seven. It had a lot to go on.
>   AMY: But why didn't it feed on us, too?
>   DOCTOR: The darkness in you pair, it would've starved to death in an instant. I choose my friends with great care. Otherwise, I'm stuck with my own company, and you know how that works out.

So the short answer is that the Doctor has way more darkness in him than they do. They're "too good" to get dark alter egos like the Dream Lord.

Comment: I'd forgotten all about that. The Wikipedia page doesn't address this titbit.

Comment: Thanks. I saw that episode a while ago. I must have forgott

Comment: I guess trying to seduce another man on the eve of your wedding still makes you more 'good' than someone who spends thousands of years saving the universe. </amy_hate>